# onchange property doesn`t work in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, object

I want to launch the function `test()` if the user inputs something in the html input field with the `id="sc1dc1"` (without using the `"onchange="` directly in HTML). What is wrong?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="text" id="sc1dc1" > 
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var x = document.getElementById("sc1dc1").value;
x.onchange = test;
function test(){alert("Test")};
```

Comment: First: you take the `value` of the element, and then address its `onchange` attribute. That is wrong. The value does not have that property. You need to remove `.value`. Also, `onchange` only fires when you leave the input field. If you want immediate response then use `oninput` instead of `onchange`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing about `onchange` events is that they only fire when the `<input>` field loses focus. If you want an immediate response, you should use `oninput` like so:

```
x.oninput = test;
```

You also need to make `x` equal to the actual *element*, not the *value* of the element. Removing:

```
.value
```

From this line:

```
var x = document.getElementById("sc1dc1").value;
```

Will fix it.

Demonstration with `onchange`:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("sc1dc1");
x.onchange = test;

function test() {
  alert("Test")
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="sc1dc1">
</body>

</html>
```

Demonstration with `oninput`:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("sc1dc1");
x.oninput = test;

function test() {
  alert("Test")
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="sc1dc1">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The javascript should be this:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("sc1dc1");
x.onchange = test;
function test(){alert("Test")};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="text" id="sc1dc1" > 
</body>
</html>
```

You don't need .value

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the function `test` to the element's `oninput` attribute. `x` should be the `HTMLInputElement`, not the value of the element.

Change

```
var x = document.getElementById("sc1dc1").value;
```

To

```
var x = document.getElementById("sc1dc1");
```

Use `oninput` instead of `onchange` if you want to trigger your event handler right when text is entered and not after the input loses focus.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("sc1dc1");
x.oninput = test;
function test(){alert("Test")};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="text" id="sc1dc1" > 
</body>
</html>
```